# Copy files from a directory which name changes everyday

Tags: powershell

There's a directory on my nas with this path: \nasname\Software\Build1.0\
In this directory you'll find the software components.

The name of the directory changes everyday, for example it's 6.95a build xxxx now. I want to copy the content of the directory while running my script to a test set up. If it would have the same name everyday, It would be:

```
Copy-Item \\nasname\Software\Build1.0\file1.exe \\pc1\DATA\destinationfolder
Copy-Item \\nasname\Software\Build1.0\file2.exe \\pc1\DATA\destinationfolder
Copy-Item \\nasname\Software\Build1.0\file3.exe \\pc1\DATA\destinationfolder
Copy-Item \\nasname\Software\Build1.0\file4.exe \\pc1\DATA\destinationfolder
```

The `Build1.0` part changes a lot, so I would like to have that bit wildcarded. 
In `\\nasname\Software` are 2 directories, `build1.0` and `Old`.

So it should be `\\nasname\software\***\file1.exe` etc, but it must not choose the `OLD` directory!

I also tried creating something like choose directory which is `not "old"` or only copy files `-notin "old"` but it can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcards in the path like so:

```
Copy-Item \\nasname\Software\Build*\file1.exe \\pc1\DATA\destinationfolder
Copy-Item \\nasname\Software\Build*\file2.exe \\pc1\DATA\destinationfolder
Copy-Item \\nasname\Software\Build*\file3.exe \\pc1\DATA\destinationfolder
Copy-Item \\nasname\Software\Build*\file4.exe \\pc1\DATA\destinationfolder
```

Or if there's only the four files you want to copy you can wildcard the file names too and use a one liner:

```
Copy-Item \\nasname\Software\Build*\file*.exe \\pc1\DATA\destinationfolder
```

Comment: That was actually so simple. I tried a wildcard, but didn't know you could word+wildcard.. Problem solved! thanks so much.

Comment: Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

If the directories are being created by the build process, you can leverage directory's last write timestamp. Like so,

```
$buildPath = '\\nas\my\build'
# Get a list of directories, sort descending by write time and pick the first one
$mostRecentDir = gci $buildPath |? { $_.psIscontainer } | sort -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | select -first 1

# Get the full path to the most recent directory
$mostRecentDir.FullName
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the build process also moves the current build to the OLD directory for the new build so all have the same timestamp. I have it solved now tho.